# React + Redux - Issue with state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am creating a react web app, in which I need to show a modal displaying several text input areas. Each `textarea` is an element of an array. It shows like this:
[Modal Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE5Ba.png).

The data is taken from the `store` using **Redux**, the data is stored inside `fat/active`: [Redux Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2tSJ.png)

If I change the text in `textarea` and close the modal without saving, nothing happens, and this is the behavior I want. I clean the element active in the store, and nothing more happens: [Clean Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cey3h.png)

The issue comes when I add a new `textarea`, or add more elements to the `array`: [Modal with several textareas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p50ok.png)

When I close the modal without saving, the store is updated with the changes. But not all of the functions that I use update the `array`: [Store Updated before cleaned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk8zI.png)

Here is the code I use:

These are the imported packaged/functions/objects

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';


import './fatmodal.css';


import { uiCloseFatPointEditModal } from '../../../../actions/ui';
import { clearActiveFatPoint, fatPointUpdate } from '../../../../actions/fat';


const customStyles = {
    content : {
      top                   : '50%',
      left                  : '50%',
      right                 : 'auto',
      bottom                : 'auto',
      marginRight           : '-50%',
      transform             : 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
      overflow              : 'auto',
      WebkitOverflowScrolling: 'touch',
    }
}

// Make sure to bind modal to your appElement (http://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/accessibility/)
// Tenemos que pasarle el elemento de nuestro index.html, es el #root
Modal.setAppElement('#root')

const initFatPoint = {
    pointId: "",
    status: "",
    result: "",
    value: "",
    nonConformity: [],
    nonConformityLength: 0,
}
```

The following code are the functions I use

```js
export const FatPointEditModal = () => {

    const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState( initFatPoint );

    const { pointId, status, result, value, nonConformity, nonConformityLength } = formValues;

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const { fatPointEditModalOpen } = useSelector(state => state.ui)

    const {active} = useSelector(state => state.fat)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
        if ( active ) {
            setFormValues( active );
        } else {
            setFormValues( initFatPoint );
        }

        console.log( formValues )
        
    }, [active, setFormValues]); 
    
    const handleNonChange = ({ target }) => {

        setFormValues({
            ...formValues,
            nonConformity: formValues.nonConformity.map( ( pt, i  ) => i === target.tabIndex 
                ? ( target.value )
                : ( pt )
            ),
        });

    }

    const handleAddNonButton = () => {

        const newNonConformity = formValues.nonConformity;

        newNonConformity.push('');

        setFormValues({
            ...formValues,
            nonConformity: newNonConformity,
        })

    }

    const handleDeleteNonButton = async () => {

        const cleanArray = formValues.nonConformity.filter( nc => nc !== '' );

        setFormValues({
            ...formValues,
            nonConformity: cleanArray,
        });

    }

    const closeModal = () => {

        dispatch( uiCloseFatPointEditModal() );

        dispatch( clearActiveFatPoint() );

        setFormValues( initFatPoint );
        
    }

    const handleSubmitForm = ( e ) => {

        e.preventDefault();
        
        dispatch( fatPointUpdate( formValues ));

        closeModal();

    }
```

And this is the return with the html code:

```js
    return (

        <Modal
            isOpen={ fatPointEditModalOpen } 
            onRequestClose={ closeModal } 
            style={ customStyles } 
            closeTimeoutMS={ 2000 } 
            className="modal"
            overlayClassName="modal-fondo"
        >
            <form 
                className="container"
                onSubmit={ handleSubmitForm }
                >   
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="subheader">No Conformidades</label>
                </div>
                {
                    ( !!nonConformity && nonConformity.length > 0 )
                        ? (
                            nonConformity.map( 
                                ( nc, i ) => <div className="container row row_edit">
                                    <div className="col-11 col">
                                        <textarea 
                                            className="form-control"
                                            rows={3}
                                            placeholder="Texto descriptivo"
                                            name={`nonConformity${ i }`}
                                            autoComplete="off"
                                            tabIndex={ i }
                                            value={ nc }
                                            onChange={ handleNonChange }
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-1 col_buttons">
                                        <button
                                            type="button"
                                            className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block edit_button"
                                            onClick={ handleAddNonButton }
                                            >
                                            <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <button
                                            type="button"
                                            className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block edit_button"
                                            onClick={ handleDeleteNonButton }
                                            >
                                            <i className="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                            
    
                        ) : ( 
                            <div></div>
                        )
                }
                <div className="row row_edit">
                    <div className="col-12 col_button">
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block col_button col-12"
                            >
                            <i className="far fa-save"></i>
                            <span> Guardar</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>

        </Modal>
    )
}
```

The action dispatched with this function `dispatch( uiCloseFatPointEditModal() )`is:

```js
case types.uiCloseFatPointEditModal:

            // Establecemos la apertura del modal del fat point en false
            return {
                ...state,
                fatPointEditModalOpen: false
            }
```

I have made some tests, printing the store in console, and the `state` has changed and it is different than the store in redux.

I don't know if there is a mistake using `useState`, `useSelector`, etc.

Apologizes for a large post, but I wanted to show all the code I have.

Any suggestion please?